# Erro ao tentar utilizar o Local Storage do HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Estou estudando sobre *local storage* em HTML5 e JS, entendendo que seu proposito é o de armazenar textos no *local storage* do *browser*.

Ao testar, obtive erros de JS. Gostaria de entender melhor o porquê:

[image: Printscreen do erro]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function exibir(){
    document.getElementById("nome").value = localStorage.getItem("l_nome");
}

</script>
<body onload="exibir();">
    <form>
        Nome: <input type="text" id="nome">
        <input type="button" onclick="salvar();" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Onde está seu método `salvar`? O erro é que ele não foi definido. Não há nenhum erro com o `localStorage`.

Answer (score 5):

Faltou apenas definir a função SALVAR:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function exibir(){
    document.getElementById("nome").value = localStorage.getItem("l_nome");
}

function salvar(){
    localStorage.setItem("l_nome", document.getElementById("nome").value);
}

</script>
<body onload="exibir();">
    <form>
        Nome: <input type="text" id="nome">
        <input type="button" onclick="salvar();" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Fiz um fiddle demonstrativo: http://jsfiddle.net/s7e53t3r

Comment: Ainda bem que faltou "apenas" isso :) ... +1

Comment: muito obrigado a todos.